# What should I set my pythonpath to

Tags: python, python-idle

I downloaded a python module from online and want to use it in IDLE, but I keep getting an error message saying it's not found.

My python path is "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin". If I want to be able to run modules I downloaded from online into IDLE, what should I set my python path to to be able to do that?

I am running OsX 10.10.5

Comment: Whats the exact error ?

Comment: prepend the folder that contains you *module* file to the [PYTHONPATH env variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: The answer should nearly always be the same whether you run the import statement with python directly or via an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory somewhere under your home directory. Let's say it's `~/pylib`. Copy the module to `~/pylib`. Before running IDLE execute the command

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/pylib
```

You should now be able to import the module.

Comment: But what's the pedantic answer?? I want the directory defined by PEP, the File System Heirarchy, or some other nebulous entity (nebulous to me). Should I make the folder hidden, such as ~/.pylib? Or I should placed in /usr/local/lib/pylib?

Comment: Oh I found it. The default directory is... `/usr/local/lib/`python*version*. See here:https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

If a module you have downloaded was properly packaged, it should come with the installation routine. Conventionally, it is called `setup.py`. If you see this file, you can just do

```
python setup.py install
```

That should take care of *most* packages available online and you don't even need to figure out where it was installed to.

If you **really** need to check/set the paths, you can check the directories as reported by

```
import sys
sys.prefix
sys.exec_prefix
```

These are the paths that point to the directories where stuff is installed (`prefix/lib`).

If you are looking into custom or user installation (using `--user` flag), check this folder: `userbase/lib/python<VERSION>/site-packages`

[More details in the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/install/)

Comment: May be I misunderstood your instructions, but I ran that script in bash and was told there is no such file or directory as setup.py

Comment: @SUPhys Go to the directory where you downloaded the package, it should be there, unless it was not packaged correctly. Give me the link to the package you are downloading.